# Keycloak, adding realm role to user via admin api on curl

Tags: bash

Using keycloak 6.0.1

I have created the realm role and the user. I have the user uuid and the role uuid.

If I run

```
curl -v -X POST -w "\n" http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/users/$USER_ID/role-mappings/realm -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" --data '[{"id":$ROLE_ID,"name":"user"}]'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /auth/admin/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/users/fe38bcb5-258b-44e4-a056-cf8c1a29b99f/role-mappings/realm HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: bearer very long string
> Content-Length: 31
> 
* upload completely sent off: 31 out of 31 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 08:53:14 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I get a server error and a log entry of

```
10:00:55,903 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-10) Uncaught server error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized token '$ROLE_ID': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Alternatively if I run curl with data of

--data '[{"id":"$ROLE_ID","name":"user"}]'

then get return of 404 not found.

If I set data to be hardcoded then it works

--data '[{"id":"9b6371f2-646d-4927-b3b6-6e208935517e","name":"user"}]'

but get return of 204 No Content which is success. And the role is added.

Further investigation -

--data '[{"id":"'$ROLE_ID'","name":"user"}]'

gives a 204 status and the role is added to the user.

So get there eventually.

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem with variable substitution:

```
$ export ROLE_ID=9b6371f2-646d-4927-b3b6-6e208935517e
$ echo '[{"id":"'$ROLE_ID'","name":"user"}]'
[{"id":"9b6371f2-646d-4927-b3b6-6e208935517e","name":"user"}]
$ echo '[{"id":$ROLE_ID,"name":"user"}]'
[{"id":$ROLE_ID,"name":"user"}]
$ echo '[{"id":"$ROLE_ID","name":"user"}]'
[{"id":"$ROLE_ID","name":"user"}]
```